# iOS xcode 4.6 Adding Audio to App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to play an audio file in the background of my app and it isn't playing. The code that I have is:

```
SystemSoundID SoundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HoHey" ofType:@"mp3"];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &SoundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
NSLog(@"%@ is playing\n", soundFile);
```

The NSLog displays "HoHey.mp3 is playing" but I can't hear it playing. My volume is turned up btw because I hear my videos play when I play them. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely have an error somewhere along the way.  Try code that looks like this:

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"HoHey" ofType:@"mp3"];
if(soundFile)
{
    OSStatus status = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFile], &soundID);
    if(status == noErr)
    {
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
        NSLog(@"%@ is playing\n", soundFile);
    } else {
        NSLog( @"no sound id created; error status code is %d", status);
    }
} else {
    NSLog( @"couldn't find sound file... is it really in your app bundle?");
}
```

P.S., don't capitalize Objective-C variable names (e.g. "`soundID`" instead of "`SoundID`").

Comment: I guess there is an error but I'm not sure why. Here's the output from NSLog: no sound id created; error status code is -1500

Comment: according to AudioServices.h, an error of -1500 is "`kAudioServicesSystemSoundUnspecifiedError`".  That's not super helpful, but it may be that something wrong with the mp3 file you've copied into the application package.

Comment: The file plays in my project if I just manually click on the HoHey.mp3 file in the project folder so that's strange. I'm getting the songs from my itunes. First I dragged a song straight from iTunes into the project and it didn't work so I figured it doesn't play .m4a files. Then I dragged the file to my desktop and renamed it with the mp3 extension and then brought it back into the project. Can I get a file from iTunes into Xcode or do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: Just because you renamed a "`.m4a`" file as a "`.mp3`" means that the file is magically converted to mp3. [According to this iPhoneFAQ](http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/9739), I don't see m4a as one of the formats that the iPhone can automagically handle. You may need to do a real conversion of the m4a file into mp3.

Comment: It asked me if I was sure I wanted to convert to mp3 format so I think it did. But I just put a mp3 file (that didn't need converting) in the project and tried that and got the same error...

Comment: So I did some more research and I believe I can only use a short (5 second) clip this way and I have a 4 minute song that I wanted to play. So I used the AVFoundation library and got it working.